Proper course of action for own question that was edited and closed
I have asked
How to silence the "default shell is zsh" warning on Stack Overflow instead of Ask Different.

Found the answer later on and updated the question:

Never mind, support.apple.com/kb/HT208050 contained the answer export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1


The answer was stripped from the question.

The question was closed.


Now it seems to be useless laying around taking up space.
What would be the best course of action?

Waste some more space and bandwidth, and ask it on Ask Different (I assume there is no easy way to just move it to a sister site)?

Abandon it?

attempt to piggyback the answer to it that someone have "thoughtfully" edited out?

Something else?



If you find an answer to your own question, you should post it as an answer, rather than editing it into the question. The answer was rightfully removed from the question because that's not where answers go - characterizing this as "mutilation" is a gross distortion of the facts. I appreciate that you can't post the answer now that the question has been closed, but it wasn't closed at the time you made the edit.

Step 1 of dealing with a mutilated and viciously closed question: don't exaggerate.

Delete it, then post the question on the correct site - where you can post the self-answer too, that's allowed. Be sure to check first it's not a duplicate.

Yes testing-malady, thanks to you and the rest of the folks in the comments who have provided detailed answers and links

Should I delete this question as well? Would be kind of a waste considering amount of work that went explaining the nitty gritty to me.

@F1Krazy please don't encourage self-answers to things that are simply off topic. That just makes cleanup harder. While the question content is the wrong place for an answer, there isn't necessarily a right place.


I have asked
How to silence the "default shell is zsh" warning

This was incorrect - it does not fall in the scope of Stack Overflow because it is not a programming question or one that uniquely applies to programmers. Many people use shells, including system administrators or even regular old power users. As such, the question did not belong to Stack Overflow to begin with.

Found the answer later on and updated the question

You should not have done this. Answers are posted in the answers section. If you do have an answer to a question of yours, then self-answer it.
See:

Should I update my question's code to include the correct answer?


The answer was stripped from the question

The action was correct and as-per the policy. As mentioned above, answers should not be part of question bodies. The usual action when that happens is to remove it.
See:

What to do when the OP posted the answer in a question edit but the question is closed?
What should we do when the OP answers his/her own question in an edit?


The question was closed.

This was again reasonable - the question was closed as "This question is not about programming or software development." As outlined in the beginning - it is off-topic and the chosen close reason is applicable.
See:

Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance - Not about programming or software development

